# How can I run test cases implementing Pytest, Playwright and Gherkin Features with Python?

Tags: python, gherkin, pytest, playwright, allure

I'm doing an end-to-end test automation project in which I simply login to a specific page. To do this, I use Python 3.10, Pytest, Playwright and Allure to report.
In my implementation file of my feature, when executing in console: `pytest --headed --alluredir=C:.../RefactorPlay/surefire-reports`. It returns me no tests ran referring to the fact that no test case to be executed is found.

Implementation file:

```
from playwright.sync_api import Page
import allure
from pytest_bdd import scenario, given, when, then
from pages.ican_login import ICanLogin

@scenario('Inicio de sesion con usuario y contraseña')
def test_example_is_working_bdd():
    print('starting bdd test')


@given("El usuario se ha registrado previamente, y los ingresa correctamente.")
def goto_website(page):
    page.goto("https://urldeejempl.com/")
    login_page = ICanLogin(page)
    login_page.fill_input_user("mail@example.com")
    login_page.fill_input_password("example")

@when("El usuario hace clic sobre el boton ingresar.")
def login_to_the_system(page):
    login_page = ICanLogin(page)
    login_page.select_submit()


@then('El usuario puede ingresar sesion a su cuenta correctamente.')
def check_ican_nav_menu(page):
    content = page.text_content("//html/body/main/aside/section/div/div[2]/div/a")
    assert content == "CONTENIDO"
```

feature file:

```
Feature: Inicio Sesion en test Sistema
  # Enter feature description here

  Scenario: Inicio de sesion con usuario y contraseña

  Given El usuario se ha registrado previamente, y los ingresa correctamente.
    When El usuario hace clic sobre el boton ingresar.
  Then El usuario puede ingresar sesion a su cuenta correctamente.
```

icanlogin.py file:

```
from playwright.sync_api import Page


class ICanLogin:
    def __init__(self, page: Page):
        self.page = page

    # Web Elements
    user: str = "#Usuario"
    password: str = "#password"
    submit: str = "#btnIngresar"
    u_forgot: str = "div:text('¿Olvidaste la contraseña?')"
    corporation_sign_up: str = "div:text('Registro de Empresas')"

    def verify_elements_is_presents(self):
        self.page.wait_for_selector(self.user)
        self.page.wait_for_selector(self.password)
        self.page.wait_for_selector(self.submit)
        self.page.wait_for_selector(self.u_forgot)
        self.page.wait_for_selector(self.corporation_sign_up)

    def fill_input_user(self, value):
        with self.page.expect_navigation():
            self.page.fill(self.user, value)

    def fill_input_password(self, value):
        with self.page.expect_navigation():
            self.page.fill(self.password, value)

    def select_submit(self):
        with self.page.expect_navigation():
            self.page.click(self.submit)

    def select_u_forgot(self):
        with self.page.expect_navigation():
            self.page.click(self.u_forgot)

    def select_corporation_sign_up(self):
        with self.page.expect_navigation():
            self.page.click(self.corporation_sign_up)
```

console error:

```
pytest --headed --alluredir=C:/Users/.../Desktop/RefactorPlay/surefire-reports
=============================================== test session starts ================================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.10.6, pytest-7.1.2, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: C:\Users\...\Desktop\RefactorPlay
plugins: allure-pytest-2.12.0, asyncio-0.20.3, base-url-2.0.0, bdd-6.1.1, dependency-0.5.1, html-3.1.1, metadata-2.0.2, playwright-0.3.0, rerunfailures-10.3
asyncio: mode=strict
collected 0 items

============================================== no tests ran in 0.04s ===============================================
```

I know that pytest takes functions that are prefixed with "test_ ..." as valid test cases. Try renaming my functions around it.

I can't detect what I'm doing wrong and I'm new to this. It's just a simple login.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that there is no test function defined in your implementation file, which is required by Pytest to identify what to run.

To fix this, add a test function in the implementation file:

```
from playwright.sync_api import Page
import allure
from pytest_bdd import scenario, given, when, then
from pages.ican_login import ICanLogin

@scenario('Inicio de sesion con usuario y contraseña')
def test_example_is_working_bdd():
    print('starting bdd test')

@given("El usuario se ha registrado previamente, y los ingresa correctamente.")
def goto_website(page):
    page.goto("https://urldeejempl.com/")
    login_page = ICanLogin(page)
    login_page.fill_input_user("mail@example.com")
    login_page.fill_input_password("example")

@when("El usuario hace clic sobre el boton ingresar.")
def login_to_the_system(page):
    login_page = ICanLogin(page)
    login_page.select_submit()

@then('El usuario puede ingresar sesion a su cuenta correctamente.')
def check_ican_nav_menu(page):
    content = page.text_content("//html/body/main/aside/section/div/div[2]/div/a")
    assert content == "CONTENIDO"
    
def test_login(page):
    goto_website(page)
    login_to_the_system(page)
    check_ican_nav_menu(page)
```

Now, you can run the test with the following command:

```
pytest --headed --alluredir=C:/Users/.../Desktop/RefactorPlay/surefire-reports
```

This will run the test and generate the Allure report in the specified directory.

Comment: I've added the function that calls the other functions, but it still doesn't work.